# flex actionscript dynamically state change and move items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, panel, move, dynamic

I'm trying to make this :
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=transitions_7.html
just press back on the bottom of this page to see the filter effect that I want

but dynamically and I did, with the states and everything for n elements. Now my question is how can I make a scroll bar on the left side but when scrolling does not need to affect the big panel so I just want to scroll for example 200 panels and not moving the big panel.
part of my code where I put states for every panel: panels is a ArrayList of panels

```
for(var i:int=0; i<6 ;i++)  
// get panel from list panels and set states
{
//addChild((panels.getItemAt(i) as Panel)); 
(states[i] as State).overrides=[ new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"x",110), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"y",0), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"width",widthBigPanel), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(i),"height",heightBigPanel)];
  var yy:int=0;
  for(var k:int=0;k<6;k++)
   {
    if(k!=i){    
(states[i] as State).overrides = (states[i] as State).overrides.concat([ new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"x",x), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"y",yy),
new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"width",widthPanel), new SetProperty(panels.getItemAt(k),"height",heightPanel)]);
       yy+=110;

      }
     }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could fix the markup in your question to format the code.  See here (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details.

Comment: @Ryan Lynch I formatted the code for @bob

Comment: the link you link to contains tips for troubleshooting transitions, it does not contain any code or samples.  As such, I'm not sure what the "this" is you are trying to "make."

Comment: The OP mentions the "back" button at the bottom of the given link.  I was going to fix the link to refer to that page directly, but the URLs are the same.  In fact, when I refreshed the page after clicking the back button, it returned to the troubleshooting page.  Odd.